# Tab UI overflow cutting element under max-width

Tags: html, css, sass

I can't wrap my head around why this tab UI is cutting the titles of my mockup while being under max-width.
max-width is 250px and some documents could overflow, that's ok, but my problem is that also the titles "a.html" are being cut while the width of the tab head is still way under the maximum allowed.

```
<div>
  <div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="doc_icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></span>
        <span class="doc_title">Document.html</span>
        <span class="actions">
          <span>
            &times;
          </span>
          <span>
            <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="doc_icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></span>
        <span class="doc_title">a.html</span>
        <span class="actions">
          <span>
            &times;
          </span>
          <span>
            <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="doc_icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></span>
        <span class="doc_title">Verylongnameforadocumentmaybethisisenough.html</span>
        <span class="actions">
          <span>
            &times;
          </span>
          <span>
            <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="doc_icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></span>
        <span class="doc_title">Thisisanothergynormousnameforanhtmldocument.html</span>
        <span class="actions">
          <span>
            &times;
          </span>
          <span>
            <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
    <div class="actions">
      <span>
        <i class="fas fa-window-restore"></i>
      </span>
      <span>
        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>

  </main>
</div>
```

//SCSS

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
  div.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;

    ul {
        display: flex;
        flex: auto;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0px;

        li {
            max-width: 250px;
            padding: 5px;
            outline: 2px solid red;

            a {
              display: flex;
              overflow: hidden;

              > span {
                align-items: center;
                height: 20px;
                flex: 0 0 20px;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;

                &.doc_icon {
                  max-width: 20px;
                  margin-right: 5px;
                }

                &.doc_title {
                  flex: auto;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  margin-right: 5px;
                }

                &.actions {
                  position: relative;
                  width: 20px;
                  height: 20px;

                  span {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                    font-size: 1em;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }

    div.actions {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
}
main {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    background: grey;
}
```

Here's a fiddle of it.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/6wsrjpeL/1/
```

What I want is being able to display titles entirely up to 250px for each tab and the maximum length of the row for all tabs, while them only in the event the parent container hasn't enough space or titles that require more than 250px.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `flex: 0 0 20px;`

Changing that rule with: `flex: 1 1 auto;` and adding your `min-width` (i.e. 20px) all works well.

This is your new sass file:

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
  div.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;

    ul {
        display: flex;
        flex: auto;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0px;

        li {
            max-width: 250px;
            padding: 5px;
            outline: 2px solid red;

            a {
              display: flex;
              overflow: hidden;

              > span {
                align-items: center;
                height: 20px;
                /*flex: 0 0 20px;*/
                flex: 1 1 auto; /* add this */
                min-width:20px; /* add this */

                text-overflow: ellipsis;

                &.doc_icon {
                  max-width: 20px;
                  margin-right: 5px;
                }

                &.doc_title {
                  /*flex: auto;*/
                  overflow: hidden;
                  margin-right: 5px;
                }

                &.actions {
                  position: relative;
                  width: 20px;
                  height: 20px;

                  span {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                    font-size: 1em;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }

    div.actions {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
}
main {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    background: grey;
}
```

And this is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wsrjpeL/2/

I put here an example with scss compiled:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.navbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

div.navbar ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: auto;
      -ms-flex: auto;
          flex: auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
}

div.navbar ul li {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

div.navbar ul li a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.navbar ul li a > span {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 20px;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  min-width:20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

div.navbar ul li a > span.doc_icon {
  max-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

div.navbar ul li a > span.doc_title {

  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

div.navbar ul li a > span.actions {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

div.navbar ul li a > span.actions span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1em;
}

div.navbar div.actions {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
          flex: 0 0 auto;
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span class="doc_icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></span>
                    <span class="doc_title">Document.html</span>
                    <span class="actions">
              <span>
                &times;
              </span>
                    <span>
                <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
              </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span class="doc_icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></span>
                    <span class="doc_title">a.html</span>
                    <span class="actions">
              <span>
                &times;
              </span>
                    <span>
                <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
              </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span class="doc_icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></span>
                    <span class="doc_title">Verylongnameforadocumentmaybethisisenough.html</span>
                    <span class="actions">
              <span>
                &times;
              </span>
                    <span>
                <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
              </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <span class="doc_icon"><i class="fas fa-file"></i></span>
                    <span class="doc_title">Thisisanothergynormousnameforanhtmldocument.html</span>
                    <span class="actions">
              <span>
                &times;
              </span>
                    <span>
                <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
              </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="actions">
            <span>
            <i class="fas fa-window-restore"></i>
          </span>
            <span>
            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <main>

    </main>
</div>
```